# After updating the NHibernate I get the LoaderExceptions error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a website worked fine locally after putting it on host-gator it is giving error http://www.akbarca.com/. Hostgator support team say that your application is running in full trust level, in this case we only allow medium trust level.

After investigation I found that the issue is in Nhibenate 2.00 which runs in Full trust level. Searching internet I found the solution is to upgrade the Nhibernate to the latest or alternatively have Install NHibernate.DependencyInjection, after I installed both now I get the error in my local computer :

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   `LoaderExceptions` property for more information.

So far I have tried the follwing with no success:
removing all the DLL and reimpoterd them.
Having Copy local true to all.

Also when I have the `[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers()]` I am getting the same error.

I think I have to have all DLL run in medium trust level, if so could you please advise on how implementing same?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same exception when we were referencing a type from a DLL that was not being copied into the bin directory of the project even though it had copy local set to true. The missing dll was not easy to find as we had to drill down into the exception's inner exceptions and their stack traces before finding the culprit. Our original investigation pointed to trust level issue but ultimately it was a dead end.  A deeper delve into the inner exceptions (I looped over the exception until innerException was null) should provide an insight into which dll is failing to load. In our case it was "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types" being referenced by a project on which our project depended and was using HierarchyId from that dll.

Comment: I have add and removed thousand times the Dlls manually and also by setting local copy true still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a few times, and it's *usually* a missing dependency, and *always* super frustrating.

The fact that the exception is thrown during Fluent's initialization can sometimes make the exception a little misleading, since it's not really a FNH exception at all. And the fact that `ReflectionTypeLoadException` also keeps exceptions as an array in the `LoaderExceptions` property also makes digging in a little more work.

Watch out to make sure that references across your individual projects are consistent. For example, I've run into this when I let R# add a dependency to a project for me that was already mapped in another project using Nuget. The second project got a reference that was good locally but that was invalid on the server (and wasn't resolved using Nuget), making it much more difficult to reproduce locally.

Anyhow, here's a code snippet that might help you track down the culprit. This example is from an MVC app employing Global.asax, but could be easily adapted to other project types.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    if (null == ex || ex is ThreadAbortException)
    {
        // could be due to redirect
        return;
    }
    if (ex is HttpException && ((HttpException)ex).GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        // don't want to log this
        return;
    }

    LogException(ex);
}

private void LogException(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception is ReflectionTypeLoadException)
    {
        foreach (Exception loaderException in ((ReflectionTypeLoadException)exception).LoaderExceptions)
        {
            LogException(loaderException);
        }
        if (null != exception.InnerException)
        {
            LogException(exception);
        }
    }
    else if (null != exception.InnerException)
    {
        LogException(exception.InnerException);
    }

    // you might also choose System.Console.WriteLine(...), System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(...), etc.
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);

    // or send to your favorite logger...this is log4net
    Log.FatalFormat("Unhandled error in the website: {0}", exception);
}
```